# PHP Load balancing for user A/B testing

Tags: php, git, apache, load-balancing

I'd like to implement some load balancing system for a PHP website.

Currently, I'm thinking about different Apache stacks and let Apache take care of the load balancing. This way I can just clone the `master` branch into a new `branch` and deploy that on a different Apache instance. This would work fine, but requires a lot of administration.

I was hoping that this is also possible in PHP itself. So that the production server folder structure would look like:

- `master/` (master branch)
- `someVariation/` (some cloned variation branch)
- `index.php` (for load balancing)

The load balancing script would then randomly balance the visitors to any branch.

Of course this is possible, but how would I change the current working directory so that anything within a branch still works the same?
What other things do I need to configure in order for this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Don't change your CWD (current working directory).

Make any "include" dependant of a constant defined in the index.php (or a "config.php"-like) of every branch:

```
<?php
define('APP_CWD', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));

// rest of your code
```